# How to connect to SQL Server using Windows Auth?

Tags: sql-server, go

I am currently using this example to connect to SQL Server using Go:

[Create Go apps](https://sqlchoice.azurewebsites.net/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/go/rhel/step/2.html)

Here is the example I am using:

```
    package main

    import (
        _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
        "database/sql"
        "context"
        "log"
        "fmt"
    )

    // Replace with your own connection parameters
    var server = "localhost"
    var port = 1433
    var user = "sa"
    var password = "your_password"

    var db *sql.DB

    func main() {
        var err error

        // Create connection string
        connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d",
            server, user, password, port)

        // Create connection pool
        db, err = sql.Open("sqlserver", connString)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error creating connection pool: " + err.Error())
        }
        log.Printf("Connected!\n")

        // Close the database connection pool after program executes
        defer db.Close()

        SelectVersion()
    }
```

Is there any known way to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server?  I have tried adding "Trusted_Connection=yes" and removing the username/password.

I have Googled around but have not found any Go Packages that have this option.

Comment: normally you don't connect as a domain user over a script but as a sql user only with limited access of course not SA.

Comment: Oh I just figured it out. "trusted_connection=yes" did work.  I just entered it wrong.

Comment: @KadeWilliams You cannot use trusted auth when you are connected via TCP, you need to make the connection over a named pipe.  Try removing the port from the connection string. If that doesn't work, try `server: np:%s` to force a named pipe connection

Comment: @KadeWilliams so please answer your own question and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BobVale, that's incorrect: it's perfectly possible to use trusted authentication over TCP—the MS-TDS protocol uses [SSPI in its handshake](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd303223), which is basically a challenge/response protocol (SPNEGO).

Comment: @kostix Ok I stand corrected, I think it's because historically trusted_connection=yes/true meant NTLM and I could never get it to work over tcp in the past.  Looking further it does depend on the provider you are using - see [Connection string Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

Comment: @BobVale, in fact is *should be* possible to negotiate NTLM via that SPNEGO exchange since it was specifically designed to be able to negotiate a specific auth mech during the GSSAPI negotiation; so on Windows, Kerberos and NTLM should be supported, in theory. But the problems may lie in a number of places including policies on different machines, two versions of NTLM in existence and whatever else. See [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/troubleshoot-ntlm.html) for one example I have personally had to deal with.

Comment: If the username is made up of DOMAIN\username - be sure to get the case right.  domain != DOMAIN.

Comment: @DB2_Philip Thanks for raising that. Indeed the fix in my case was prepending the ActiveDirectory Name before username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I posted earlier...

"trusted_connection=yes" did work. I just entered it wrong.

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm using it like: `connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;port=%d;trusted_connection=yes;", server, port)`

Comment: did not help too

Answer (score 1):

In my workplace we are using GORM which uses go-mssqldb to connect to the SQL Server. The following connection string format worked for us:

```
sqlserver://DATABASE_HOSTNAME:1433?database=DATABASE_NAME&trusted+connection=yes&app+name=APPLICATION_NAME
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, if I try to connect through Goland datasources it works, but if I put the following dsn:

sqlserver://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@HOST:1433?database={DATABASE}&trusted+connection=yes&app+name=jTDS

I get login failed, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Your client side setup was correct. Did you add the windows user account to to the Database? I have done this multiple time without issues. Make sure your windows auth is enabled in your Db and the user has sufficient previlages.

[steps to connect to sql server using windows authenticaton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx)